# Do all body organs grow in proportion during the period of physical development?

Tags: human-anatomy, development, growth, organs

It is obvious that during childhood and puberty, the human body grows uniformly or proportionally so that a child's arm length, for example, is shorter than an adult's arm length but is proportional to a child's leg length.

What I'd like to know is whether the same is true for internal organs, or are there any organs (even external but perhaps less obvious) that do not grow in dimensions when the rest of the body grows and develops (I am talking about physical growth).

Comment: Careful: what you claimed to be obvious (*"during childhood and puberty, the human body grows uniformly or proportionally"*) is not what happens! Actually, that's what led the pre-renaissance painters depict child Jesus in the [Madonna paintings](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/madonna-virgin-mary-child-jesus-mosaic-tile-painting-byzantine-style-icon-street-as-votive-image-wall-55949491.jpg) as a strange, miniaturised adult. Human body grows disproportionately during childhood.

Comment: I suggest reading this wikipedia article [Allometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allometry)